# CloudBlob.ExistsAsync cost

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am designing an Azure app and I have to estimate the costs per call type that I will be generating in Azure.

One of the Azure calls I plan to use is [CloudBlob.ExistsAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.existsasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_ExistsAsync) and I am not sure if I am gonna get charged money for it or not?
The documentation is not specific on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will, primarily transaction count cost since the banwidth cost is very little for HEAD blob requests.